# RoR: How to Change fields on Join statement generated by Active Record's sum function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sum

I'm doing a sum using the Sum function provided by RubyOnRails' Active Record as follows:

```
s=DatosMateria.sum('inscritos',:conditions=> "datos_materia.ano=2005 AND materias.codigo=2394",:include=>"materias")
```

it returns 0 and generates me the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT sum('datos_materia'.inscritos) AS  sum_inscritos FROM 'datos_materia' LEFT OUTER JOIN 'materias' ON materias.codigo=datos_materia.id WHERE..
```

I need it to join on fields materias.codigo=datos_materia.materia_codigo instead of materias.codigo=datos_materia.id (materias.codigo and datos_materia.id are both primary keys and they're not the same type nor associated keys.)

The involved models are shown below:

```
 
class DatosMateria < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_table_name 'datos_materia'
    has_many :materias,:foreign_key => 'codigo'
end
```

class Materia < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_primary_key 'codigo'
    belongs_to :datosMateria, :foreign_key=> 'materia_codigo'
end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** After reworking this post I've come to the conclusion that your relationship between Materia and DatosMateria are wrong. It looks like you've got belongs_to and has_many backward. You mention that materias.codigo and datos_materia.id are both primary keys. That you want to join on the materia primary key implies that materia should have many datos_materia, and not the other way around as your assocations are defined.

In short: the description of your associations and problem, it looks like  were trying to save the primary key of the one side of a one one to many relation ship as a foreign key on the many side. This is not how relational databases work. The way they usually go is the many side of a one to many relationship will store the primary key of the associated record as a foreign key.

It looks like a few things have gotten lost in translation. So here's a better explanation of what's wrong with your relationships.

Rails expects foreign keys to be named "#{foreign_class}_id", and will store the id associated foreign class. The foreign key is always found on the belongs_to side of things.

With the relationships defined in the question.

All association helper methods called on DatosMateria or an instance of it will join on `datos_materia.id = materias.codigo`.

Where the foreig\n_key is expected to be materias.codigo. But materias.codigo the primary key, so how can a materia be linked to a datos_materia?

```
@datos_materia.materias.create
```

Will create a new Materia record with @datos_materia.id stored in the Materia's codigo's column. Where as establishing the relationship the other way around will create the new materia with @datos_materia.materia_codigo stored in the materia's codigo column.

```
Materia.create(:datos_materia => @datos_materia)
```

Assocation helper methods called on Materia or an instance of it will join on `datos_materia.id = materias.materia_codgio`

There is no simple fix. You will need to redefine your models and completely rework your tables. Assuming you were looking to set up that one materia has many datos_materia. Here are the correctly defined relationships you were going for:

```
class DatosMateria < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'datos_materia'
  belongs_to :materias, :foreign_key => :materia_codigo
end

class Materia < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :datos_materias, :foreign_key => :materia_codigo
end
```

However one you've defined your relationship properly your Sum will work as it should.

Comment: Thanks for your response, the field materia_codigo is not the primary key but the associated field to 'codigo' in my Materia Model. I tried your answer and didn't worked out for me.

Comment: I glossed over some details on account of the language used. I've found the root of your problem and updated my answer. But it's not good news.

Comment: Thank you EmFi. As you said it I had the association backwards. I rewrote the models just like you put it with some details: belongs_to :materia without the S, has_many :datosMaterias,and finally, adding the set_primary_key 'codigo' in Materia Model. Thank you again.